# pheatmap - cytokine_annotation

Tags: r, pheatmap

I tried to develope cytokine_annotation in pheatmap and get error message

> Error in seq.int(rx[1L], rx[2L], length.out = nb) : 'from' must be
>   finite

R version 3.3.3
pheatmap_1.0.8

Reproducible example:

```
#Using cytokine annotations
M<-matrix(rnorm(8*20),ncol=8)
row_annotation<-data.frame(A=gl(4,nrow(M)/4),B=gl(4,nrow(M)/4))
eg<-expand.grid(factor(c(0,1)),factor(c(0,1)),factor(c(0,1)))
colnames(eg)<-c("IFNg","TNFa","IL2")
rownames(eg)<-apply(eg,1,function(x)paste0(x,collapse=""))
rownames(M)<-1:nrow(M)
colnames(M)<-rownames(eg)
cytokine_annotation=eg
pheatmap(M,annotation=annotation,row_annotation=row_annotation,annotation_legend=TRUE,row_annotation_legend=TRUE,cluster_rows=FALSE,cytokine_annotation=cytokine_annotation,cluster_cols=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my R 3.3.3 with pheatmap_1.0.8 the following code works:

```
set.seed(1)
M <- matrix(rnorm(8*20),ncol=8)
row_annotation <- data.frame(A=gl(4,nrow(M)/4),B=gl(4,nrow(M)/4))
eg <- expand.grid(factor(c(0,1)),factor(c(0,1)),factor(c(0,1)))
colnames(eg) <- c("IFNg","TNFa","IL2")
rownames(eg) <- apply(eg,1,function(x)paste0(x,collapse=""))
rownames(M) <- 1:nrow(M)
colnames(M) <- rownames(eg)
cytokine_annotation <- eg
library(pheatmap)
pheatmap(M, annotation=cytokine_annotation, row_annotation=row_annotation,
            annotation_legend=TRUE, row_annotation_legend=TRUE, cluster_rows=FALSE,
            cytokine_annotation=cytokine_annotation, cluster_cols=FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and found that simply restarting R solved this issue.